# Model.Summary() displays incorrect shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

When I run my model he compiles fine and there is no problem.
However, when I use the model.summary() to view my model it seems like it displays incorrect info.

```
def train_model():
    global history

    train, validation = DataReceiver.receive_for_level('train', BATCH_SIZE), DataReceiver.receive_for_level('validation', BATCH_SIZE)
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    # model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    #model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    #model.add(layers.Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    #model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Dense(NB_CLASSES, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),

    filepath = "saved-model-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5"
    checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=False, mode='min')

    best_filepath = 'best-saved-model-{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.hdf5'
    best_model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(best_filepath, monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')

    print(model.summary())
    history = model.fit(train[0], steps_per_epoch=train[1], validation_steps=validation[1],
                        epochs=30, validation_data=validation[0], verbose=1, callbacks=[checkpoint, best_model_checkpoint])

    return model
```

for the following model with Input shape of (150, 150, 3)
I get the following result:

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 148, 148, 32)      896       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D  (None, 74, 74, 32)       0         
 )                                                               
                                                                 
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 72, 72, 32)        9248      
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling  (None, 36, 36, 32)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           (None, 34, 34, 64)        18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling  (None, 17, 17, 64)       0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           (None, 15, 15, 64)        36928     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling  (None, 7, 7, 64)         0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 conv2d_4 (Conv2D)           (None, 5, 5, 128)         73856     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling  (None, 2, 2, 128)        0         
 2D)                                                             
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 2, 2, 128)         0         
                                                                 
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 512)               0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 4)                 2052      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 141,476
Trainable params: 141,476
Non-trainable params: 0
```

It seems like the Conv2D decreases (2, 2) from his shape every time.

Comment: You use max_pooling2d.

Comment: does it cause to the input shape to be (148, 148) instead of (150, 150) ?

Comment: try this code: `import tensorflow as tf      input_shape = (4, 28, 28, 3)
      x = tf.random.normal(input_shape)      
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape[1:])(x)      
print(y.shape)`

Comment: There is nothing wrong here, that is how Conv2D works with the parameters you are using.

Comment: And more importantly, you should say why you think its wrong, not just point and something and say its wrong without any justification.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the padding mode. When a sliding window moves horizontally through the image data or convolves, one column in left, one in right are missed (2 pixels). The same law holds for vertical movements, where a row in top and another in bottom are missed(2 pixels altogether). All of this means loosing some information. This is for padding = "valid" parameter in a Conv2D layer, which defaults to this mode if not mentioned.

You can also use padding = "same" which doesn't decrease input size after convolution operation. After this, all the shrinking operations are caused by pooling layers.